# Single word for "working without details"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, adverbs

I'm looking for one word that expresses lack of information, lack of knowledge and lack of guidance. The word is an adverb.

It could be used in a sentence like so:

> He was working on a project ...

*Proactively* is close, but it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: 'unsupervised', 'independently'.

Comment: How would *proactively* be close to that concept?

Comment: Robusto, what I'm looking for has a quality of being proactive in terms of embarking on a task/journey even though the exact path is not known. Think of Frodo in Lord of the Rings, he went onto a journey proactively even though he didn't know the way to Mordor.

Comment: At my company, doing so is the status quo. :)

Comment: @Pompair - Proactive means acting in advance or with initiative.  I don't think Frodo is a stellar example of someone being proactive, but even if he were - it wouldn't have anything to do with him knowing the way (or not).   I'm voting to close because it's kind of a fishing expedition for 'guess what I'm thinking', and I think that's not constructive.

Comment: Lynn, yes you're right about "proactive", it was merely mentioned as a feel for the word, as in having a momentum of going forward. I'm afraid I can't see how searching for exactness of expression wouldn't be constructive. Eventually, I found the word by contemplating for an hour, the word was "speculatively".

Comment: This question can be improved by supplying the required research. As it stands the question is incomplete.

Comment: I think you're describing [*autodidacticism*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodidacticism), the corresponding adverb being [*autodidactically*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/autodidactically), except that leaves you with one hideous sentence. Better reword.

Answer (score 3):

"Blindly" is what instantly comes to mind for me.

Comment: Yes - except I'd actually say *"I'm working **blind** on this project"*, rather than ***blindly*** (even though the word is being used adverbially).

Answer (score 0):

[Extemporaneously](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/extemporaneously):

> In an extemporaneous manner; **without prior preparation or planning.**
>
> *Considering that he was speaking **extemporaneously**, he covered the subject pretty well.*

[Offhandedly](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/offhand) is another candidate. The thesaurus has an entry for [extemporaneous](http://thesaurus.com/browse/extemporaneous) which should point to other choices.

Comment: This is good, very close to what I'm looking for, alas it's not the word I'm looking for. I heard the word years ago and I know I recognise it when I see it. Do you have any other synonyms for this? PS: the word is not included in the list of synonyms in the linked thesaurus.